# Write error while trying to save a int into a text fil, how would I fix this?

Tags: python

Alright, I'm trying to save three raw input variables to a text file. Every thing works fine until it gets to appending (I think that's what it's called) the information to the text file. 
It gets down to the 2nd variable on the list, which is age, and then prints this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Management CMS\employee-management.py", line 7, in <module>
    fileObj.write(age)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

My code is:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?")
age = int(raw_input("How old are you?"))
favcolor = raw_input("What is your favorite color?")

fileObj = open("employee.txt","w")
fileObj.write(name)
fileObj.write(age)
fileObj.write(favcolor)
fileObj.close()
print "The following text has been saved:"
print name
print age
print favcolor
```

Comment: "second variable in the list" is not age, it's a freaking **integer**. how's that you're not seeing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer probably expect a string. It should be:

```
age = raw_input("How old are you?")
```

You can still cast it as an integer to make sure it is an int before writing the value to the buffer, but if python can't convert it, it will raise an error.

Comment: why not `str(str(str(str(raw_input("How old are you?")))))`